# It's okay to declare other components inside a component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, performance

Imagine that I have a List of Cards on my react application. So I will have two components, the `<ListCard />` and `<Card />`.
My doubt is that where I work, when we have something like this, we usually declare a variable inside the `<ListCard />` named `Card` that receives a JSX, but I don't know if this is a good thing to do. Recently I faced some problems with this approach, but I didn't find anyone saying to do it or not.

*Imagine that I'm not using the `<Card />` anywhere in the application*

The way we would declare the **ListCard**

```
const ListCard = () => {
  const cards = [
    { title: '1', id: 1 },
    { title: '2', id: 2 },
  ];

  const Card = ({ title }) => <div>{title}</div>;

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>List of Cards</h1>
      {cards.map(card => (
        <Card title={card.title} key={card.id} />
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};
```

I want to know if it's better to declare outside of the ListCard, like this.

```
const Card = ({ title }) => <div>{title}</div>;

const ListCard = () => {
  const cards = [
    { title: '1', id: 1 },
    { title: '2', id: 2 },
  ];

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>List of Cards</h1>
      {cards.map(card => (
        <Card title={card.title} key={card.id} />
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: outside is correct ... the patterns is to declare any component in their own file ; i mean each file for each component

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It is totally fine to declare another `Component` in the same file, but declaring it inside another one's function would be inefficient. Imagine your app 'recreating' the second `Component` during each `render`.

So, feel free to declare it in the same file, but don't do it inside another `Component`'s function.

Answer (score 6):

In a functional component, every variable gets destroyed and recreated again every render. This is what makes the `useState` hook so valuable, as it is smart enough to recreate it's variables with the previous or updated values.

By declaring a component inside another component, you are not only re-rendering both components, but completely redeclaring one. This won't be very performant, especially if the component is more complex.

So the answer to your question is always declare it separate. It would work declared inside, but there's no benefits from it, only drawbacks.

Comment: This is not very accurate. The answer should mention that "redeclaring" a component means that the previous instances will be dismounted and remounted on every render. Also, you mention useState, which is the hook least related to the OP's question. Using useMemo or useCallback would make it perfectly possible to declare a component inside a component.

Answer (score 3):

Contrary to what is said in the other answers, it **might** be perfectly fine to declare components inside a component. It can even be quite useful in some situations where you need to access functions from the parent scope, and when rendering each item would be costly. The only thing is that you need to understand what you're doing, be careful, and do it correctly. But you will learn that, with React hooks, any approach always need you to have a good understanding of the render process.

In your case, to prevent remounting the component on every render, you need to keep the same reference on the child component you are creating. For that, we use the `useMemo` hook. Be careful, because each time a dependency of that hook updates, your reference will change and so the children will remount. There are ways to work around this and always keep the same reference, but that might be a bit off-topic.

Here is a common example:

```js
const List = ({ items, onItemSelected }) => {

  // If you don't use useMemo, your component will be recreated every time and
  // React will destroy and recreate every item at every render.
  const Item = React.useMemo(() => ({ index, item }) => {
    const onClick = React.useCallback(() => onItemSelected(index), [index])
    return <li onClick={onClick}>{item}</li>
  }, [onItemSelected])

  return (<ul>
    {items.map((item, index) => <Item key={index} index={index} item={item} />)}
  </ul>)
}
```

You can find a complete working example [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/goofy-hermann-m7k926?file=/src/App.js)

Here is the full code with some comments you might want to pay attention to.

```js
import React from "react";

const items = ["apple", "banana", "orange"];

export default function App() {
  const [selected, setSelected] = React.useState(-1);
  const onItemSelected = React.useCallback((index) => setSelected(index), []);
  return (
    <div>
      {/* Add some logs and see what happens if you add "selected={selected}" to the props of List */}
      <List items={items} onItemSelected={onItemSelected} />
      <p>
        You pressed <b>{items[selected]}</b>
      </p>
    </div>
  );
}

// We used React.memo so the list won't rerender when the parent state changes
// This is a good optimization, but nothing mandatory, here
const List = React.memo(({ items, onItemSelected }) => {
  // If you don't use useMemo, your component will be recreated every time and
  // React will destroy and recreate every item at every render.
  const Item = React.useMemo(() => {
    // We use this syntax only for eslint to detect that this is a component.
    // There is nothing mandatory, here, neither.
    const Component = ({ index, item }) => {
      // The main interess here, is that "onItemSelected" is not a prop anymore.
      // This way, we can make onClick a callback that won't change between renders
      const onClick = React.useCallback(() => onItemSelected(index), [index]);
      return <li onClick={onClick}>{item}</li>;
    };
    Component.displayName = "Item";
    return Component;
    // be very carefull with what you put here. The component should not depend on things
    // That might change often, because every items will be destroyed and recreated when they change
    // Try to add "selected" in this dependency list and see the impacts on rerender
  }, [onItemSelected]);

  return (
    <ul>
      {items.map((item, index) => (
        <Item key={index} index={index} item={item} />
      ))}
    </ul>
  );
});
```

Comment: *It can even be quite useful in some situations* - like what? The situation you've included as code is *far* more complex and error prone than just extracting `Item` into it's own top-level component.

Suggesting that this pattern is *perfectly fine* is frankly irresponsible. At best it's acceptable for edge cases, which your answer does not explain or provide.

Comment: If you extract Item as its own component, as mentioned in the comments, onClick will be a function that is recreated during each render for each item, forcing each item to rerender. There are other ways to solve this, but they all have flaws and feel less natural (according to me, but I'm opened to discussion). In the first code sample, I'm just wrapping the component in a useMemo. What do you feel complex about it? About error prone... Well, it's as error prone as using React in the first place. The proof of that is the code provided by the OP. I'm opened to chat if you want.

Comment: It's error prone because it's very common that dependencies get missed in useMemo hooks that cause skipped re-renders (which is of course the point of the hook when you do it right), unexpected skipped renders can be very very difficult to track down (I've had to do several). Re-rendering items in a list is typically a very cheap operation, and if the component is complex/expensive to render, then useMemo is a perfect use-case. I just feel that it should be highlighted that this is only a desirable approach with expensive components, and not something to be used on any and all lists

Comment: React hooks without using eslint-plugin-react-hooks is like running on a minefield anyway... I'll edit my post to be a bit more explicit on the risks involved for beginners.

Comment: Personally, I value the way that nesting code (in this case react components) adds to the understanding of the code when the nesting is meant to show the developer's intentions regarding scope. (i.e. how visible or reusable something is intended to be). To me the expressiveness [regarding scope] is more valuable than performance (unecessary re-renders), or the likelihood of missing a dependency with useMemo.  I see good or bad code as a value judgement not a universal truth. So, if you or your teams values on a given project can provide a similar justification then I think it's perfectly fine.