# react input field will loose focus when filtering data

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have a list of array and when I start typing in the `input` list of array will filter corresponding to the `value`. It works but I loose focus in the `input` after typing a character.

My code:

```
const MyPage = (props) => {

  const [searchTerm, setSearchTerm] = useState("");

  const results = !searchTerm
      ? people
      : people.filter(person =>
          person.toLowerCase().includes(searchTerm.toLocaleLowerCase())
        );

  const handleChange = event => {
      setSearchTerm(event.target.value);
    };

  const Desktop = ({ children }) => {
    const isDesktop = useMediaQuery({ minWidth: 992 })

    return (
      isDesktop?
      <View>
          <input
          type="text"
          placeholder="Search"
          value={searchTerm}
          onChange={handleChange}
          />
          <View style={{width:100, height:100, backgroundColor:'red'}}>
            {results.map(item => (
              <Text>{item}</Text>
            ))}
          </View>
      </View>
      :null
    )
  }

  return(
    <View style={{width:'100%',justifyContent:'center'}}>
      <Desktop/>
    </View>
  )
}
```

Instead of returning `<Desktop/>` if I directly put

```
<input
          type="text"
          placeholder="Search"
          value={searchTerm}
          onChange={handleChange}
          />
          <View style={{width:100, height:100, backgroundColor:'red'}}>
            {results.map(item => (
              <Text>{item}</Text>
            ))}
          </View>
```

It will work. Any idea how to fix this issue?

Any advice or comment will be appreciated!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think put your isDesktop variable  outside the component scope and use useCallback to wrap your handleChange function

Comment: @HarishJangra thanks for the comment I don't really now much about useCallback could you show me how?

Answer (score 8):

[Moving the `Desktop` component outside of the `MyApp`](https://codesandbox.io/s/clever-hypatia-yr9s8) component fixes this issue. The major reason for this is that the `Desktop` component gets recreated on each render (every time you type), which causes the input element to lose its focus. You could also somewhat mitigate this by using the `useCallback` and `useMemo` hooks, both [described in detail in the official React documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html), but in this example they're not needed.

Also see [this answer on declaring other components within a component](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59777102/795759).

Answer (score 2):

Use `autoFocus={true}` property of the input

Answer (score 1):

Also as an hacky trick you can use `autoFocus` property of your input:

```
        <input
          autoFocus={true}
          type="text"
          placeholder="Search"
          value={searchTerm}
          onChange={handleChange}
    />
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you have a component inside a component. So when your state changes, the `Desktop` component gets **re-initialized**, which causes the `input` to lose focus. I merged both components in one. If you actually need `Desktop` to be it's own component, then you might want to declare `Desktop` outside of `MyPage` and pass `searchTerm, results, handleChange` as props to `Desktop`.

```
const MyPage = props => {
  const [searchTerm, setSearchTerm] = useState("");
  const isDesktop = useMediaQuery({ minWidth: 992 });

  const results = !searchTerm
    ? people
    : people.filter(person =>
        person.toLowerCase().includes(searchTerm.toLocaleLowerCase())
      );

  const handleChange = event => {
    setSearchTerm(event.target.value);
  };

  return (
    <View style={{ width: "100%", justifyContent: "center" }}>
      {isDesktop && (
        <View>
          <input
            type="text"
            placeholder="Search"
            value={searchTerm}
            onChange={handleChange}
          />
          <View style={{ width: 100, height: 100, backgroundColor: "red" }}>
            {results.map(item => (
              <Text>{item}</Text>
            ))}
          </View>
        </View>
      )}
    </View>
  );
};
```