# React layout state change re-renders child routes in outlet

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, react-router-dom

I am making a react application that uses a layout to display routes passed to it. The layout has a header and a sidebar that can open and close. When the sidebar is opened or closed it causes a rerender of the pages being displayed in the outlet. Not a big deal except the pages will interact with an api (currently done with use effect) which is triggering every time the drawer is opened or closed, which seems super unnecessary and inefficient.

I’ve tried wrapping the outlet in a memo to prevent rerendering however that didn’t have any effect.

Layout:

```
//react
import { Outlet } from 'react-router-dom';
import { useState } from 'react';

//mui
import { styled } from '@mui/material/styles';

//project
import { Header } from '../features/Header';
import { SideBar } from '../features/SideBar';
import { BackgroundBox } from '../core/BackgroundBox';

// ==============================|| MAIN LAYOUT ||============================== //

const MainLayout = () => {
  const drawerWidth = 240;

  const Main = styled('main', { shouldForwardProp: (prop) => prop !== 'open' })(
    ({ theme, open }) => ({
      flexGrow: 1,
      padding: theme.spacing(3),
      transition: theme.transitions.create('margin', {
        easing: theme.transitions.easing.sharp,
        duration: theme.transitions.duration.leavingScreen
      }),
      marginLeft: 0,
      ...(open && {
        transition: theme.transitions.create('margin', {
          easing: theme.transitions.easing.easeOut,
          duration: theme.transitions.duration.enteringScreen
        }),
        marginLeft: `${drawerWidth}px`
      })
    })
  );

  const DrawerHeader = styled('div')(({ theme }) => ({
    display: 'flex',
    alignItems: 'center',
    padding: theme.spacing(0, 1),
    // necessary for content to be below app bar
    ...theme.mixins.toolbar,
    justifyContent: 'flex-end'
  }));

  const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);

  return (
    <BackgroundBox>
      <Header open={open} setOpen={setOpen} DrawerHeader={DrawerHeader} drawerWidth={drawerWidth} />
      <SideBar open={open} drawerWidth={drawerWidth} setOpen={setOpen} />
      <Main open={open}>
        <Outlet />
      </Main>
    </BackgroundBox>
  );
};

export default MainLayout;
```

sample page to be rendered in the outlet:

```
//react
import { React, useState, useEffect } from 'react';

//mui
import { Typography } from '@mui/material';

//Project Imports
import { ContentCard } from '../../components/core/ContentCard';
import { gridSpacing } from '../../configuration/config';

// ==============================|| SAMPLE PAGE ||============================== //

const SamplePage1 = () => {
  const [data, setData] = useState('');
  useEffect(() => {
    const dataFetch = async () => {
      const data = await (await fetch('/api/sampleFunction1')).text();
      setData(data);
    };
    dataFetch();
  }, []);

  const cardSx = {
    margin: gridSpacing
  };

  return (
    <ContentCard title={'Sample Page One'} cardSX={cardSx}>
      <Typography variant="body1">
        This is the first sample page, the server responded with: {data}
      </Typography>
    </ContentCard>
  );
};

export default SamplePage1;
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to move `Main` outside the body of `MainLayout`.

Otherwise, `Main` gets recreated every time `MainLayout` re-renders (i.e. when the drawer is toggled) and everything below it in the tree gets remounted (not just rerendered)

```
// move Main up here
  const Main = styled('main', { shouldForwardProp: (prop) => prop !== 'open' })(
    ({ theme, open }) => ({
      flexGrow: 1,
      padding: theme.spacing(3),
      transition: theme.transitions.create('margin', {
        easing: theme.transitions.easing.sharp,
        duration: theme.transitions.duration.leavingScreen
      }),
      marginLeft: 0,
      ...(open && {
        transition: theme.transitions.create('margin', {
          easing: theme.transitions.easing.easeOut,
          duration: theme.transitions.duration.enteringScreen
        }),
        marginLeft: `${drawerWidth}px`
      })
    })
  );


const MainLayout = () => {
  const drawerWidth = 240;


  const DrawerHeader = styled('div')(({ theme }) => ({
    display: 'flex',
    alignItems: 'center',
    padding: theme.spacing(0, 1),
    // necessary for content to be below app bar
    ...theme.mixins.toolbar,
    justifyContent: 'flex-end'
  }));

  const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);

  return (
    <BackgroundBox>
      <Header open={open} setOpen={setOpen} DrawerHeader={DrawerHeader} drawerWidth={drawerWidth} />
      <SideBar open={open} drawerWidth={drawerWidth} setOpen={setOpen} />
      <Main open={open}>
        <Outlet />
      </Main>
    </BackgroundBox>
  );
};
```

While you're at it, move `DrawerHeader` outside as well for efficiency.

You should never declare components inside the function body of another component.

Here's a related SO answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59776934/954940, though I wouldn't call it a dupe.